# TikZ ordering of paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

Without the [extremely cool macros by John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410379/121799) and the [very helpful answer by Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410567/121799) I would not have been able to come this far. My ultimate aim is to make it easy to fake 3D spheres with Ti*k*Z. This already works quite well, but I wanted to try a different, arguably more direct approach to draw the relevant objects. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
% parametrizations from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410379/121799
\newcommand{\latitudearc}[4]{% #1=label (optional), #2=latitude
%#3 start angle #4 end angle
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410567/121799
  \global\let\RX=\RX % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352269/121799
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RY}{\RX*sin(\Clat)}%
  \global\let\RY=\RY
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\CY}{\RadiusSphere*sin(#2)*cos(\Clat)}
  \global\let\CY=\CY
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xend}{\RX*cos(#4)}
  \global\let\Xend=\Xend
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yend}{\CY+\RY*sin(#4)}
  \global\let\Yend=\Yend}%
  plot [domain=#3:#4,smooth,#1] ({\RX*cos(\noexpand\x)},{\CY+\RY*sin(\noexpand\x)})
}
% compute ellipse rotation=\ROT, xradius=\RX, arc angle at equator=\LAT
\newcommand{\longitudearc}[4]{% #1=label (optional), #2=longitude
%#3 start angle #4 end angle
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\ROT}{atan2(sin(\Clat)*sin(#2-\Clong),cos(#2-\Clong))}% alpha
  \global\let\ROT=\ROT
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\LAT}{asin(cos(\Clat)*cos(\ROT))}% north pole theta_n
  \global\let\LAT=\LAT
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*tan(\LAT)*tan(\ROT)}% r_x
  \global\let\RX=\RX
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DELTAX}{-90+\LAT}
  \global\let\DELTAX=\DELTAX
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xend}{\RX*cos(\ROT)*cos(#4+\DELTAX)-\RadiusSphere*sin(\ROT)*sin(#4+\DELTAX)}
  \global\let\Xend=\Xend
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yend}{\RadiusSphere*cos(\ROT)*sin(#4+\DELTAX)+\RX*sin(\ROT)*cos(#4+\DELTAX)}
  \global\let\Yend=\Yend
  }
  plot[domain=#3:#4,smooth,#1]({\RX*cos(\ROT)*cos(\noexpand\x+\DELTAX)-\RadiusSphere*sin(\ROT)*sin(\noexpand\x+\DELTAX)},
  {\RadiusSphere*cos(\ROT)*sin(\noexpand\x+\DELTAX)+\RX*sin(\ROT)*cos(\noexpand\x+\DELTAX)})
}
\newcommand{\hotspot}[3]{% #1=label (optional), #3=latitude, #2=longitude
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#3)} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410567/121799
  \global\let\RX=\RX % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352269/121799
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RY}{\RX*sin(\Clat)}%
  \global\let\RY=\RY
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\CY}{\RadiusSphere*sin(#3)*cos(\Clat)}
  \global\let\CY=\CY
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xloc}{\RX*cos(#2)}
  \global\let\Xloc=\Xloc
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yloc}{\CY+\RY*sin(#2)}
  \global\let\Yloc=\Yloc}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\RadiusSphere{4}% sphere radius
\def\Clat{20}% point of view latitude
\def\Clong{-90}% point of view longitude
\shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);


\hotspot{0}{-120}{-40}
\filldraw (\Xloc,\Yloc) circle (0.2);
\hotspot{0}{-120}{30}
\filldraw (\Xloc,\Yloc) circle (0.2);
\hotspot{0}{-50}{-40}
\filldraw (\Xloc,\Yloc) circle (0.2);
\hotspot{0}{-50}{30}
\filldraw (\Xloc,\Yloc) circle (0.2);


\begin{scope}
\clip[variable=\x] \longitudearc{blue}{-120}{-40}{30} 
%\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-50}{-40}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
\latitudearc{blue}{30}{-120}{-50} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
%\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-120}{-40}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc) % <-NEEDED? 
\longitudearc{blue}{-50}{30}{-40} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
%\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-120}{30}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
\latitudearc{blue}{-40}{-50}{-120} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
%\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-50}{30}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
-- cycle;
\shade[ball color = blue!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not quite what I wanted. However, if I uncomment the `\pgfextra` commands in the `scope` at the bottom, i.e. use the `scope`

```
\begin{scope}
\clip[variable=\x] \longitudearc{blue}{-120}{-40}{30} 
\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-50}{-40}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
\latitudearc{blue}{30}{-120}{-50} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-120}{-40}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc) % <-NEEDED? 
\longitudearc{blue}{-50}{30}{-40} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-120}{30}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
\latitudearc{blue}{-40}{-50}{-120} %to ({\Xend},{\Yend})  
\pgfextra{\hotspot{0}{-50}{30}} to  (\Xloc,\Yloc)  % <-NEEDED?
-- cycle;
\shade[ball color = blue!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
\end{scope}
```

instead, I get:

[image]

which is almost precisely what I want. (The upper and lower boundaries are incorrect.) That is, by artificially inserting points into the path, I can get the shape bounded by plots. In the upper figure it seems that Ti*k*Z for some reason always "completes" the individual plots by returning to the starting points. Now my question is whether or not there is a way to switch that off.

**EDIT**: Here is a very minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\node[text width=3.5cm] at (1,5){with cycle};
\path[draw,blue,variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) --  plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)})  -- cycle; 
\clip[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) -- plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)}) -- cycle; 
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=4cm}] 
\node[text width=3.5cm] at (1,5){path closed by hand};
\path[draw,blue,variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) --  plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)})  -- (0,0); 
\clip[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) -- plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)}) -- (0,0); 
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=10cm}] 
\node[text width=3.5cm] at (1,5){a somewhat more complex example};
\path[draw,blue,variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) --  plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)})  
 plot ({-\x},{-4+\x*\x})-- (0,0); 
\clip[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (0,0) --  plot ({\x},{\x*\x})
 plot ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)})  
 plot ({-\x},{-4+\x*\x})-- (0,0);
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\draw [red,dashed] (0,0) -- (2,4);
\draw [red,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As one can see, the clipping is only correct (or, at least, as I think it should be) in the middle plot where I closed the path by hand. In the right plot, even though I close the path by hand, the clipping is not as it should be, I think. I also added the red dashed lines that seem to suggest that each of the plots form a closed path. But the middle example shows that this is not always case. Is there a way to always have the behavior as in the middle example *without* adding coordinates by hand?

Comment: @cfr Well, thanks for your example, I had a very [similar one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410539/121799) earlier on. As far as I see it, the issue really arises when I construct a path of several plots. And the commands `\longitudearc` and `\latitudearc` are very explicit, you really only need the last lines of those, e.g. `plot [domain=#3:#4,smooth,#1] ({\RX*cos(\noexpand\x)},{\CY+\RY*sin(\noexpand\x)})`. But thanks for looking into this anyway!

Comment: @cfr No, because then you'd expect to clip like in the upper figure. I really want to construct a boundary by following the first plot from the lower to the upper end of the domain, then the next one, and so on.

Comment: @cfr The issue arises regardless of whether or not I put `\cycle` at the end of the sequence. The last plot ends (or, more precisely, is supposed to end) where the first one begins.

Comment: @cfr I added a very minimal example that seems to suggest that the problem is always there.

Comment: In your very minimal example, add `--` between the plots of each clip path  to get the correct result (the `clip` operation is like a `fill` operation).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks! But this seems to be an accident, try `\clip (0,0) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2] ({\x},{\x*\x})
-- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2] ({1*(2-\x)},{4*(1-\x)})  
-- plot[variable=\x,domain=-2:0] ({\x+2},{4+(\x+2)*(\x+2)})-- (0,0);` instead. Here I put `--` before, between, and after the plot.

Comment: The result seems correct with the example in your previous comment... What result did you expect?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, you're right! Very helpful!

Comment: The filling examples p.170 (pgfmanual, v3.0.1a) are explicit: _All unclosed parts of the path are first closed, if necessary_. Note: the `clip` operation always use the `nonzero rule`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Sorry, this is not too helpful. In the first example, there is no need to "close" the paths.

Comment: Each `plot` begins by an implicit `move to` operation if not preceding by `--` (p.326, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, thanks! But I still don't quite understand what is considered the first coordinate of the plots. In the "somewhat more complex example", the first coordinate of a given plot is the last coordinate of the previous one. So, according to this, no `--` should be necessary.

Comment: The implicit `move to` operation is included even if the coordinates are the same.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Sadly, in the example on the spheres I fail to put `--` for reasons that I do not understand. I can put `-- (\Xend,\Yend)` where `\Xend` and `\Yend` are the final coordinates of the last or first coordinates of the next plot, but this does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each plot begins by an implicit move to operation if not preceding by `--` (p.326, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a). The implicit move to operation is included even if the current point is the same as the first coordinate of the plot.

To get a single closed path, you must link your plot operations by `--`. But TikZ does not allow to call a macro after a `--`: you can't use your `\latitudearc` macro after `--`.

Here is a solution more in the spirit of TikZ. This solution no longer uses macros but keys to define coordinates (`hot spot`) or to build arcs (`latitude arc` and `longitude arc`).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzset{
  hot spot/.style n args={2}{% #1=longitude, #2=latitude
    /utils/exec={
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410567/121799
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\RY}{\RX*sin(\Clat)}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\CY}{\RadiusSphere*sin(#2)*cos(\Clat)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xloc}{\RX*cos(#1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yloc}{\CY+\RY*sin(#1)}
    },
    at={(\Xloc,\Yloc)},
  },
  latitude arc/.style n args={4}{% #1=additional keys for plot, #2=latitude, #3 start longitude, #4 end longitude
    to path={
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410567/121799
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\RY}{\RX*sin(\Clat)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\CY}{\RadiusSphere*sin(#2)*cos(\Clat)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xend}{\RX*cos(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yend}{\CY+\RY*sin(#4)}
      }%
      -- plot [domain=#3:#4,#1] ({\RX*cos(\x)},{\CY+\RY*sin(\x)}) -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
  longitude arc/.style n args={4}{% #1=additional keys for plot, #2=longitude, #3 start latitude, #4 end latitude
    to path={
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ROT}{atan2(sin(\Clat)*sin(#2-\Clong),cos(#2-\Clong))}% alpha
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\LAT}{asin(cos(\Clat)*cos(\ROT))}% north pole theta_n
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*tan(\LAT)*tan(\ROT)}% r_x
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\DELTAX}{-90+\LAT}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xend}{\RX*cos(\ROT)*cos(#4+\DELTAX)-\RadiusSphere*sin(\ROT)*sin(#4+\DELTAX)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yend}{\RadiusSphere*cos(\ROT)*sin(#4+\DELTAX)+\RX*sin(\ROT)*cos(#4+\DELTAX)}
      }
      --
      plot[domain=#3:#4,variable=\x,#1]({\RX*cos(\ROT)*cos(\x+\DELTAX)-\RadiusSphere*sin(\ROT)*sin(\x+\DELTAX)},
      {\RadiusSphere*cos(\ROT)*sin(\x+\DELTAX)+\RX*sin(\ROT)*cos(\x+\DELTAX)})
      -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\RadiusSphere{4}% sphere radius
  \def\Clat{20}% point of view latitude
  \def\Clong{-90}% point of view longitude
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);


  \coordinate[hot spot={-120}{-40}] (p1);
  \coordinate[hot spot={-120}{30}] (p2);
  \coordinate[hot spot={-50}{-40}] (p3);
  \coordinate[hot spot={-50}{30}] (p4);

  \begin{scope}
    \clip
    (p2) to[latitude arc={}{30}{-120}{-50}]
    (p4) to[longitude arc={}{-50}{30}{-40}]
    (p3) to[latitude arc={}{-40}{-50}{-120}]
    (p1) to[longitude arc={}{-120}{-40}{30}]
    cycle;
    \shade[ball color=blue!40,opacity=.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
  \end{scope}

  \path \foreach \num in {1,...,4}{(p\num) node{p\num}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just wondering if you and @JohnKormylo want to turn this into a package....